# Data structure for set operations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

What data structure supports the following set operations efficiently both in time and space?

1. union
2. difference
3. ismemberof
4. add
5. delete

I can think of 3 different ways to do these operations, suppose that we have two sets, their sizes are both N:

**Bit Array:**

```
1. O(N)  2.O(N)  3.O(1)  4.O(1)  5.O(1)
```

**HashTable:**

```
1. O(N)  2.O(N)  3.O(1)  4.O(1)  5.O(1)
```

**Ordered Tree**:

```
1. O(NlogN)  2.O(NlogN)  3.O(logN)  4.O(logN)  5.O(logN)
```

Bit Array and HashTable are fast but they use too much memory, Ordered Tree is slow but consumes less memory.

Please note: the set may contain other types except integer, such as float number or string

What other data structures are both fast and general, and space efficient?

Comment: What is the application where you're trying to use this data structure?

Comment: This might help if you are considering JAVA http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Why can't a hash table (hash set) hold arbitrary (but comparable) objects just like an ordered tree?

Comment: For log analysis, not all operations are needed, but i am curious.

Comment: @Ted Hopp you are right, i made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to augment your ordered tree with a bloom filter to speed up the `ismemberof` type tests.

I *think* that the overall behaviour would be something like:

```
1. O(N log(N) )  2. O( ? )  3.O(1)  4.O(log(N))  5.O( log(N) )
```

However the exact details will depend on the size of the filter, the size of your sets and the size of your domain.

Another option may be [Judy Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judy_array). I've heard good things about them for this kind of use, but  have no personal experience.

Yet another option is a [forrest approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289153%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (rather than a pure binary tree).

Comment: bloom filter may give false positive?

Comment: Yep it certainly can - but its negatives are always valid. So you search the tree if it returns a positive, but you avoid a tree traversal if it gives you a negative.

Comment: i will look into judy array, it seems interesting

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest [Binary Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) (the easiest one), [Binomial Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_heap) (speeding up union) and [Fibonacci Heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap) (hardest to implement, but having the best known amortized times for standard operations).

**Operation                
Binary Heap
               
Binomial Heap
               
Fibonacci heap (amortized)**
1. union
                         O(n)                            O(logn)                                  O(1)
2. difference               O(nlogn)                         O(nlogn)                                O(nlogn)
3. find(ismemberof)      O(n)                              O(n)                                     O(n)
4. add                           O(lgn)                           O(lgn)                                    O(1)
5. delete                       O(lgn)                           O(lgn)                                    O(lgn)

However, these structures are mostly used when **insert, find/extract min(max), union** and **delete** operations are needed. **find** and **diff** operations still have poor running time.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look into [Union-Find Data Structure](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=7XUSn0IKQEgC&pg=PA198&lpg=PA198&dq=union%20find%20data%20structure%20skiena&source=bl&ots=z79GLTMQ-m&sig=J-U4RxNh24PWFqSoJY4IueDDQbc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DTMeUO7OAsvQrQfgp4HACw&ved=0CFkQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=union%20find%20data%20structure%20skiena&f=false)